# Werden vor und nach »gegeben durch …« Kommas gesetzt?

Tags: comma, parenthesis

> Die Funktion f von IR nach IR**,** gegeben durch f(x) = x²**,** ist nicht injektiv.

Ist die Kommasetzung in diesem Beispiel richtig? Muss man die Kommas setzen?

Answer (score 5):

Das ist kein Deutsch, das ist "mathematisch" ;).

Von daher greifen die Regeln der deutschen Zeichensetzung hier nur bedingt. Betrachtet man den Teil "gegeben durch..." als verkürzten Relativsatz (ihm fehlen ein paar wichtige Komponenten dazu), gehören da Kommas hin. Tatsächlich ist das eine sogenannte *eingeschobene Partizipgruppe*, die durch Kommas getrennt werden **kann**, aber nicht muß. (Amtliche Zeichensetzungsregeln, §78).

Gerade in mathematischen Texten würde ich im Übrigen **Klarheit** deutlich bevorzugen, vor allem da die Kommas keine ganzen Wörter, sondern mathematische Formelbestandteile trennen, d.h. im Zweifelsfall lieber Kommas setzen.

Comment: Könntest du kurz erläutern, wieso du mehrfach auf die Besonderheit der mathematischen Sprache hinweist? Abgesehen von in nicht-mathematischen Texten etwas ungebräuchlicher Wortwahl (*gegeben durch* an Stelle von *angegeben als* oder *definiert als*) sehe ich insbesondere grammatikalisch keine Abweichung von der Standardsprache. "Der Schuster Paul Müller, angemeldet mit Startnummer 42, ist zu langsam." - gleiche grammatikalische Konstruktion, nur gebräuchlichere Worte.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, das sehe ich auch so, inhaltlich ist es aber eher wie: „Der Teilnehmer angemeldet mit der Startnummer 42 ist zu langsam.“ Ich wüsste auch gerne, wie da Kommas zu setzen sind.

Comment: @CarstenS: Ich sehe den inhaltlichen Unterschied zwischen meinem und deinem Beispielsatz ehrlich gesagt nicht. Beide entsprechen der auf [canoonet](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/Zusatz.html) genannten Konstruktion "Der Prinz, überwältigt von so viel Glück, küsste ihren Mund." Und damit heißt es auch "Der Teilnehmer, angemeldet mit der Startnummer 42, ist zu langsam." Vielleicht willst du darauf hinaus, dass in *der Teilnehmer* noch kein bestimmter Teilnehmer gemeint ist und dieser erst durch die nachfolgende Einschränkung der Startnummer ...

Comment: ... spezifiziert wird? Das würde ich beim vom OP genannten Satz aber bestreiten, denn die Funktion ist ja schon vor dem Einschub *gegeben durch f(x) = x²* spezifiziert, und zwar durch ihren Namen, *f*. In deinem Beispiel ist das beim Teilnehmer nicht der Fall, wodurch es aber meines Erachtens erforderlich wird, dass sich *der Teilnehmer* auf eine bereits in  vorhergehenden Sätzen spezifizierte Person bezieht. Ansonsten ergäbe der Satz keinen Sinn und müsste "*Ein* Teilnehmer, angemeldet mit der Startnummer 42, ist zu langsam." lauten.

Answer (score 0):

Das ist eine Apposition, die hier durch die Kommata abgetrennt wird. Wenn du den eingeschobenen Teil weg lässt, hast du immer noch einen Sinn tragenden Satz.